# Grouping and calculating data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm almost a newbie with Pandas, so I'd like to know if a certain operation is possible before start coding around it.

I have a set of data of employees' working hours, like this
(These are oversemplified, the real stuff is thousand and thousand of records)

```
    ID      Name    Date        Hour    Type
0   123     Bob     01/01/2018  09:00   In
1   123     Bob     01/01/2018  09:30   Out
2   123     Bob     01/01/2018  10:00   In
3   123     Bob     01/01/2018  12:00   Out
4   123     Bob     01/01/2018  13:00   In
5   123     Bob     01/01/2018  17:00   Out
6   456     Max     01/01/2018  09:00   In
7   456     Max     01/01/2018  12:00   Out
8   456     Max     01/01/2018  13:00   In
9   456     Max     01/01/2018  17:00   Out
10  123     Bob     02/01/2018  09:00   In
11  123     Bob     02/01/2018  09:30   Out
12  123     Bob     02/01/2018  10:00   In
13  123     Bob     02/01/2018  17:00   Out
14  456     Max     02/01/2018  10:00   In
15  456     Max     02/01/2018  17:00   Out
```

I know how powerful Python and Pandas are in manipulating data, I'd like to know if there's away to get this kind of output whithout going through iterative coding

```
    ID      Name    Date        HourWorked
0   123     Bob     01/01/2018  06:30
1   456     Max     01/01/2018  07:00
2   123     Bob     02/01/2018  07:30
3   456     Max     02/01/2018  07:00
```

In the end, what I need is (for every employee ID) calculating the hours/minutes worked for every single day

I watched a lot of GroupBy examples, but I found anything useful.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the hours to `datetime`, `groupby` the In's and Outs' and take the difference. Later sum the difference grouping by `'ID'` and `'Date'` i.e

```
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'])

df['diff'] = df.groupby((df['Type'] == 'In').cumsum())['Hour'].diff()

df_new = df.groupby(['ID','Name','Date'])['diff'].sum().to_frame('Hours Worked')

                    Hours Worked
ID  Name Date                   
123 Bob  01/01/2018     06:30:00
         02/01/2018     07:30:00
456 Max  01/01/2018     07:00:00
         02/01/2018     07:00:00
```

Comment: Yes,I couldn't think of using `timedelta` :)

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm :)
The only weird thing is when I try to write with df_new.to_excel(), all the Hours Worked are = 0

Comment: @I3g10n3 you can now vote on all the helpful solutions. Leave a vote too :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby` + a custom function. This assumes your "In" & "Out" times are correctly paired and ordered.

```
# convert series to timedelta
df['Hour'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour']+':00')

# define total time calculation
def total_time(x):
    return (x.iloc[1::2].values - x.iloc[::2].values).sum()

# apply groupby and convert to dataframe
res = df.groupby(['ID', 'Name', 'Date'])['Hour'].apply(total_time)\
        .to_frame('Hours Worked').reset_index()

print(res)

    ID Name        Date  Hours Worked
0  123  Bob  01/01/2018      06:30:00
1  123  Bob  02/01/2018      07:30:00
2  456  Max  01/01/2018      07:00:00
3  456  Max  02/01/2018      07:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes however that your `Type` is always in a "In-Out" order

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [123,123,123,123,456,456, 123,123, 456,456],
                   "Date": ["01/01/2018","01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", 
                       "02/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "02/01/2018"],
                   "Hour": ["09:00","09:30","10:00","12:00","13:00","17:00", "10:00","12:00","13:00","17:00"],
                   "Type": ["In","Out","In","Out","In","Out", "In","Out","In","Out"]})
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Hour"] + " " + df["Date"])
df.groupby(["ID", "Date"])["DateTime"].apply(list).\
                                       apply(lambda x: [x[i+1] - x[i] for i in range(len(x) - 1)]).str[0::2].\
                                       apply(lambda x: np.sum(x))
```